# Links in Eclipse Java stack trace console - How to open in the current window set?

Tags: eclipse

**My setup:**  In Eclipse, I have multiple projects open simultaneously.  Each project is actually a different CVS branch of the same project codebase.  I use Eclipse window working sets to switch between the branches.  When I select a particular window working set, Eclipse will hide the other window working sets, allowing me to work on one branch at a time.

**My problem:**  When I paste an exception stack trace into the Java Stack Trace Console, the links in the stack trace are opening the copy of the *.java file from a different branch than the one in the currently selected window working set.  That is, it opens the copy from HEAD instead of the copy from REL_3_1, even though HEAD is hidden and only REL_3_1 is visible.

How do I tell Eclipse to open the copy that belongs to the currently selected window working set?

**UPDATE:**  As I was preparing to submit a bug on Eclipse Bugzilla, I found that the issue was not happening anymore.  I did not update or modify Eclipse.  However, I did clean and rebuild my open projects.  I wonder if this is an intermittent issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug, please open a bug against JDT/Debug at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/. Also I presume you wanted to say 'Window working sets' and not 'Window sets'

Comment: Thank you.  I'll open a bug within the next couple of days.